# Configuring some parameter in ejabberd.yml file

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I want to configure a parameter say MYNAME="Heelo" in ejabberd.yml.How to do that and how to get that parameter in erl file?

Comment: You mean your own module?

Comment: yes I want to get parameter configured in ejabberd.yml from my own module

Answer (score 1):

For each Ejabberd module two functions must be implemented, `start/2` and `stop/1`. The `start/2` function needs two arguments, `Host` and `Options`. Ejabberd calls each `start/2` function of the modules you specified in `ejabberd.yml` one by one when you start Ejabberd and it converts the provided YAML options to Erlang terms and passes them to `start/2` function as argument.

This way you can fetch the YAML options as follows:

#### ejabberd.yml

```
modules:
  mod_custom:
    key_1: value_atom
    key_2: "value_binary"
    key_3: 123456
    key_4:
      - item_1
      - item_2
      - item_3
```

#### mod_custom.erl

```
-module(mod_custom).
-behaviour(gen_mod).

start(Host, Options) ->
  Val1 = proplists:get_value(key_1, Options), %% Val1 = value_atom
  Val2 = proplists:get_value(key_2, Options), %% Val2 = <<"value_binary">>
  Val3 = proplists:get_value(key_3, Options), %% Val3 = 123456
  Val4 = proplists:get_value(key_4, Options), %% Val4 = [item_1,item_2,item_3]
  %% ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the custom modules which hook up to events in Ejabberd.

Following are the list of events of ejabberd:

```
c2s_stream_features(Acc)
c2s_unauthenticated_iq(Acc, Server, IQ) -> Packet
roster_get(Acc, {User, Server}) -> [RosterItem]
roster_get_jid_info(Acc, User, Server, JID) -> {Subscription, Groups}
roster_get_subscription_lists(Acc, User, Server) -> {[FromSubscription],[ToSubscription]}
roster_in_subscription(Acc, User, Server, JID, SubscriptionType, Reason) -> bool()
roster_out_subscription(Acc, User, Server, JID, SubscriptionType, Reason) -> bool()
roster_process_item(RosterItem, Server) -> RosterItem
disco_local_features(Acc, From, To, Node, Lang) -> Adhoc
disco_local_identity(Acc, From, To, Node, Lang) -> Adhoc
disco_local_items(Acc, From, To, Node, Lang) -> Adhoc
disco_sm_features(Acc, From, To, Node, Lang) -> Adhoc
disco_sm_identity(Acc, From, To, Node, Lang) -> Adhoc
disco_sm_items(Acc, From, To, Node, Lang) -> Adhoc
adhoc_local_items(Acc, From, To, Lang) -> Adhoc
adhoc_sm_items(Acc, From, To, Lang) -> Adhoc
ejabberd_ctl_process(Args) -> CtlStatus
filter_packet({From, To, Packet}) -> {From, To, Packet}
local_send_to_resource_hook(From, To, Packet) -> ok
offline_message_hook(From, To, Packet) -> ok
pubsub_publish_item(Host, Node, From, To, ItemId, Payload) -> ok
remove_user(User, Server) -> ok
resend_offline_messages_hook(Acc, User, Server) -> [Route]
resend_subscription_requests_hook(Acc, User, Server) -> [Packet]
sm_register_connection_hook(SID, JID, Info) -> ok
sm_remove_connection_hook(SID, JID, Info) -> ok
unset_presence_hook(User, Server, Resource, Status) -> void()
user_available_hook(JID) -> ok
user_receive_packet(JID, From, To, Packet) -> ok
user_send_packet(From, To, Packet) -> ok
privacy_check_packet(Acc, User, Server, PrivacyList, {From, To, Packet}, Dir) -> Auth
privacy_get_user_list(Acc, User, Server) -> PrivacyList
privacy_iq_get(Acc, From, To, IQ, ActiveList) -> {result, Packet} | {error, Error}
privacy_iq_set(Acc, From, To, IQ) -> {result, Packet} | {error, Error}
privacy_updated_list(Acc, OldPrivacyList, NewPrivacyList) -> PrivacyList
```

You can find the Events and hooks with example here [https://www.ejabberd.im/Events+and+Hooks](https://www.ejabberd.im/Events+and+hooks) and the Official docs here [https//docs.ejabberd.im/developer/hooks/](http://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/hooks/).

Basically writing your custom modules, registering/adding to your `ejabberd.yml` file will be like

```
modules:
  mod_custom: []
```

Here is the tutorial which I found best to create the module for ejabberd : http://happy.cat/blog/XMPP-Bots-ejabberd-mod-motion-2010-02-01-10-00.html

Another example of ejabberd stanza ack which is customely developed: h[ttps://github.com/Mingism/ejabberd-stanza-ack](https://github.com/Mingism/ejabberd-stanza-ack)

Comment: @yashwanh:May be you misunderstood my question.I want to get a parameter from ejabberd.yml programatically.For example registration_timeout .This parameter exists in ejabberd,yml .How can i get this parameter in my module.